# Efficient way of handling file management?

Tags: file-management, file-transfer, script

So I work for this small company and what they currently have is a bunch of files on server being move from one place to another. They are in pdf, wpd, doc and xls format. Initially what happens is that a user creates an entry into an excel file, then creates a folder on the server and then populate the folder with all the required files. After that a backup is created and an html version is created for the people in manufacturing.

I told my boss that we could have a script running on server, all the user has to do is to drop the files on the server and let the script take care of everything, but he is not a fan of scripts running on server.

Any ideas how this can be automated or anyone has done something that they might want to share.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not just have the user manually invoke the script once the Excel file is updated?  This should put your boss at ease, because then there won't be a daemon polling in the background waiting for the file to be updated.

Comment: but would there be a problem if more than one user tries to run the script at the same time?

Comment: You could make the script check for other instances first, and if so delay until completed.

Comment: Um yes - I'd automate this with a script running on the server!

Comment: is there another solution where it does not involve running script on the server? I am thinking of a GUI version where the user can browse for files, backup etc.

Comment: i wish my boss could think like you guys!!! I hate people with money but no brain (aka my boss)

Comment: Maybe he'd be better with a scheduled task as opposed to a script "listening" 24/7?

Comment: Or if server stability is his concern, the script could be run on any machine as long as the account it was running under had access to the share. Having said that I would still vote for a scheduled task on the server unless there is a time constraint issue and the script would need to immediately run whenever a new file appeared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Rollup Of Comments

#### Suggestion 1: Manual Script

A script could be available that is explicitly run by the user to do the work when they place a new file on the share. The script would have to be intelligent enough to know if another user is already running it.

Pro: There is no daemon type process running on the server to potentially cause stability issues.
Con: The user has to remember to run the script.

#### Suggestion 2: Scheduled Task

A script could be run periodically by the task scheduler service on the server.

Pro: No daemon and no user action required.
Con: If the time interval for the scheduled task is too long conversions may not happen soon enough.

#### Suggestion 3: Different Location

Either of the above solutions or even a daemon running on a different machine.

Pro: Very unlikely to cause stability issues on the server. Provides the pros of whichever solution is used.
Con: Kind of kludgie (just my opinion). Susceptible to connectivity issues.